# yii2: how to get slider range value

Tags: yii2, yii-extensions, yii-components, yii2-user, yii2-model

i use kartik-v/yii2-slider in my project .

with this code i added one slider A range select :
[image]

```
echo '<b class="badge">$10</b> ' . Slider::widget([
    'name'=>'rating_3',
    'value'=>'250,650',
    'sliderColor'=>Slider::TYPE_GREY,
    'pluginOptions'=>[
        'min'=>10,
        'max'=>1000,
        'step'=>5,
        'range'=>true
    ],
]) . ' <b class="badge">$1,000</b>';
```

i  have 2 column for min value and max value in (set_money) table :
min_money 
max_money

how i can save thats variable in my database !

I do not know how to get that variable in controller

Comment: After you send your form data to your controller you will be able to get it in Yii::$app->request->get('rating_3') or Yii::$app->request->post('rating_3') , depending on method you sending data from form. So in controller try to handle form submit with if(Yii::$app->request->post('rating_3')) // process data and save it to DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**in view file, in form**

```
<?php
echo '<b class="badge">$10</b> ' . Slider::widget([
    'name'=>'min_money',
    'value'=>'250,650',
    'sliderColor'=>Slider::TYPE_GREY,
    'pluginOptions'=>[
        'min'=>10,
        'max'=>1000,
        'step'=>5,
        'range'=>true
    ],
]) . ' <b class="badge">$1,000</b>';
```

**in controller**

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Model; // give your actual model name instead of Model
    if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()))
    {
        list($model->min_money, $model->max_money) = explode(',', $model->min_money);
        // now both $model->min_money and $model->max_money are set and contains value submitted in form by Kartik Slider Widget
        if($model->save(true))
        {
            // success -> redirect
        }
        else
        {
            // error render to form again
        }

    }
}
```